# Number of $k\times n$ matrices of rank $k$

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

> How can I determine the number of $k\times n$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb F_p$ with rank $k$ (of course $k<n$)

The formula if $k=n$ is $(p^n-1)(p^n-p)\dots(p^n-p^{n-1})$, now how can I modify this ?

If I pick any $k$ columns of $n$, and apply the formula, and let the $n-k$ columns be arbitrary, then this causes multiple counting, but I don't know how many times I count.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The matrix has $k$ rows and $n$ columns. Considering $k \le n$, it has rank $k$ if and only if the $k$ rows are linearly independent. So:

- There are $p^n - 1$ choices for the first row (it can't be $0$)
- There are $p^n - p$ choices for the second row (it can't be in the span of the first row)
- There are $p^n - p^2$ choices for the third row (it can't be in the span of the first two rows)

and so on. So the number of matrices total is simply
$$
\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} (p^n - p^i) = (p^n - 1)(p^n - p)(p^n - p^2) \cdots (p^n - p^{k-1}).
$$

You will also notice this agrees  (and is the exact same argument) with the case $n = k$.

Things would become a bit more complicated if we wanted to count matrices with rank $j$, where potentially $j < k$.

Answer (score 3):

A supplementary answer to 6005's answer is given here.  Let $q=p^k$ for some prime natural number $p$ and for some positive integer $k$.  Fix two positive integers $m$ and $n$.  The number of $m$-by-$n$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}_q$ of rank $r$, where $r$ is a nonnegative integer less than or equal to both $m$ and $n$, is given by $$\left(\prod_{j=1}^r\,\left(q^m-q^{j-1}\right)\right)\,\left(\sum_{\substack{{j_1,\ldots,j_r\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}}\\{j_1+j_2+\ldots+j_r\leq n-r}}}\,q^{\sum_{i=1}^r\,i\,j_i}\right)\,.\tag{1}$$ which is also equal to $$\left(\prod_{j=1}^r\,\left(q^n-q^{j-1}\right)\right)\,\left(\sum_{\substack{{j_1,\ldots,j_r\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}}\\{j_1+j_2+\ldots+j_r\leq m-r}}}\,q^{\sum_{i=1}^r\,i\,j_i}\right)\,.\tag{2}$$
According to Marko Riedel in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1859676/algebraic-or-analytic-proof-of-a-polynomial-identity), (1) and (2) are equal to
$$\prod_{j=1}^r\,\frac{\left(q^m-q^{j-1}\right)\,\left(q^n-q^{j-1}\right)}{q^{j-1}\left(q^j-1\right)}=\prod_{j=1}^r\,\frac{q^{j-1}\,\left(q^{m-j+1}-1\right)\,\left(q^{n-j+1}-1\right)}{\left(q^j-1\right)}\,.$$

If $r=m$ and $m\leq n$, then the second expression is precisely $\displaystyle \prod_{j=1}^m\,\left(q^n-q^{j-1}\right)$, as 6005 has stated.  In the extreme case, $r=0$, both expressions evaluate to $1$ (since the number of $0$-subsets of $\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ whose sum is less than or equal to $m-r$ or $n-r$ is $1$, which counts only the empty set).  In the case $r=1$, the answer is $$\displaystyle\left(q^m-1\right)\,\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\,q^j\right)=\frac{\left(q^m-1\right)\left(q^n-1\right)}{q-1}=\left(q^n-1\right)\,\left(\sum_{j=0}^{m-1}\,q^j\right)\,.$$
It is an interesting question whether there is an algebraic or analytic argument that proves that (1) and (2) are equal (by treating $q$ as a variable, and proving that these two polynomials in $q$ are identical, for example, via balancing the coefficients).