# Algebraic or Analytic Proof of a Polynomial Identity

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, polynomials, finite-fields, analytic-functions

> Let $m$, $n$, and $r$ be integers with $0\leq r \leq \min\{m,n\}$.  Define
>   $$f_{m,n,r}(q):=\left(\prod_{j=1}^r\,\left(q^m-q^{j-1}\right)\right)\,\left(\sum_{\substack{{j_1,\ldots,j_r\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}}\\{j_1+j_2+\ldots+j_r\leq n-r}}}\,q^{\sum_{i=1}^r\,i\,j_i}\right)\,,$$
>   so that
>   $$f_{n,m,r}(q)=\left(\prod_{j=1}^r\,\left(q^n-q^{j-1}\right)\right)\,\left(\sum_{\substack{{j_1,\ldots,j_r\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}}\\{j_1+j_2+\ldots+j_r\leq m-r}}}\,q^{\sum_{i=1}^r\,i\,j_i}\right)$$
>   as polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}$ in the variable $q$.  Prove that $$f_{m,n,r}(q)=f_{n,m,r}(q)\,.$$

Here is a combinatorial proof of this identity.  The polynomial $f_{m,n,r}(q)$ counts the number of $m$-by-$n$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}_q$ of rank $r$, when $q$ is a power of a prime natural number.  Since the transpose map from $\text{Mat}_{m\times n}\left(\mathbb{F}_q\right)\to\text{Mat}_{n\times m}\left(\mathbb{F}_q\right)$ is a bijection that preserves rank, we conclude that the number of $n$-by-$m$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}_q$ of rank $r$ is also $f_{m,n,r}(q)$.  Ergo, $f_{m,n,r}(q)=f_{n,m,r}(q)$ whenever $q$ is a prime power, whence the equality $f_{m,n,r}(q)=f_{n,m,r}(q)$ is indeed an identity in $\mathbb{Z}[q]$.  See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1859512/number-of-k-times-n-matrices-of-rank-k).

Comment: Hello there, I would appreciate it that you do not edit for aesthetic reasons and take questions to the comments first! Thank you.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel I'm sorry, but I was a bit confused by the occurrences of $q$ in your answer.  However, you can always roll it back, if you dislike how I edited your answer.

Comment: The main problem is that you may inadvertently introduce errors that were absent from the previous version. I just checked everything and it looks okay. BTW physicists use $j$ for the imaginary unit and I have contour integrals in my answer which is why I do not use $j$ as an index in combinatorial sums.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel  I see.  Again, I'm sorry.  On the bright side, physicists who care about combinatorics are unlikely confused by the use of $j$ as indices, and understand that mathematicians use $i$ for $\sqrt{-1}$.  :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We conjecture that

$$f_{m,n,r}(z) = 
\left(\prod_{j=1}^r (z^m-z^{j-1})\right)
\left(\prod_{j=1}^r (z^n-z^{j-1})\right)
\frac{(-1)^r}{z^{r(r-1)/2}} \prod_{j=1}^r \frac{1}{1-z^j}.$$

If we can prove this we have the symmetry. We must show that

$$\left(\prod_{j=1}^r (z^n-z^{j-1})\right)
\frac{(-1)^r}{z^{r(r-1)/2}} \prod_{j=1}^r \frac{1}{1-z^j}
= [w^{n-r}] \prod_{j=0}^r \frac{1}{1-wz^j}.$$

The LHS is

$$\begin{align}
&\left(\prod_{j=1}^r z^{j-1} \prod_{j=1}^r (z^{n-(j-1)}-1)\right)
\frac{(-1)^r}{z^{r(r-1)/2}} \prod_{j=1}^r \frac{1}{1-z^j}
\\&\phantom{aaaaaaa} = \left(\prod_{j=1}^r (z^{n-(j-1)}-1)\right) (-1)^r 
\prod_{j=1}^r \frac{1}{1-z^j} 
\\&\phantom{aaaaaaa} = (-1)^r 
\prod_{j=1}^r \frac{1}{1-z^j}
\prod_{j=n-(r-1)}^n (z^j-1)
\\&\phantom{aaaaaaa} = \prod_{j=1}^r \frac{1}{z^j-1}
\prod_{j=n-(r-1)}^n (z^j-1).\end{align}$$

We are therefore tasked with showing that

$$\prod_{j=n-(r-1)}^n (z^j-1)
= [w^{n-r}] \frac{1}{1-w} \prod_{j=1}^r \frac{z^j-1}{1-wz^j}.$$

This can be done by induction. We have for $r=1$

$$\begin{align}z^n-1 &= [w^{n-1}] \frac{1}{1-w} \frac{z-1}{1-wz}
\\ &= [w^{n-1}]\left(\frac{z}{1-wz} - \frac{1}{1-w}\right)
= z \times z^{n-1} - 1.\end{align}$$

For the induction step we have for the RHS by the induction hypothesis
multiplying both sides of the equation for $r$ by $z^{n-r}-1$

$$(z^{n-r}-1) 
[w^{n-r}] \frac{1}{1-w} \prod_{j=1}^r \frac{z^j-1}{1-wz^j}.$$

The first piece here is

$$\frac{z^{n-r}}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{w^{n-r+1}} 
\frac{1}{1-w} \prod_{j=1}^r \frac{z^j-1}{1-wz^j} \; dw.$$

Now put $w/z=v$ so that $dw = z\; dv$ to get

$$\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|v|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{v^{n-r+1}} 
\frac{1}{1-vz} \prod_{j=1}^r \frac{z^j-1}{1-vz^{j+1}} \; dv
\\&\phantom{aaaaaaa} = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|v|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{v^{n-r+1}} 
\prod_{j=1}^r \frac{z^j-1}{1-vz^{j}}\frac{1}{1-vz^{r+1}} \; dv.\end{align}$$

Now

$$\frac{1}{1-vz^{r+1}} - \frac{1}{1-v}
= \frac{1}{1-v} \frac{1}{1-vz^{r+1}}
\big(1-v-\left(1-vz^{r+1}\right)\big)
\\ = v \frac{1}{1-v} \frac{z^{r+1}-1}{1-vz^{r+1}}$$

and we obtain

$$\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|v|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{v^{n-r+1}} \frac{v}{1-v}
\prod_{j=1}^{r+1} \frac{z^j-1}{1-vz^{j}} \; dv
\\&\phantom{aaaaaaa} = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|v|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{v^{n-r}} \frac{1}{1-v}
\prod_{j=1}^{r+1} \frac{z^j-1}{1-vz^{j}} \; dv.\end{align}$$

This is

$$[v^{n-(r+1)}] \frac{1}{1-v} \prod_{j=1}^{r+1} \frac{z^j-1}{1-vz^j}$$

and we are done.